# How to use map function for two arrays and concatenate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have two arrays.

```
const test = ["SME","ONE", "TWO"]
const test2 = ["RED"]  // can have multiple elements
```

I am trying to map over this and return an  object like this :

```
[{SME: "SME", isValid: Y}, {ONE: "ONE", isValid: Y}, {"TWO": isValid: Y}, {"RED": "N"}]
```

How can I create such Data structure using map ?

I tried :

```
test.map((item) => ({
   item,
    isValid: Y
})

test1.map((item) => ({
   item,
isValid: N
})

[...test, ...test2]
```

This way it works , but any other solution for this ? We can not combine these two arrays at start

Comment: What's wrong with this solution?

Comment: `[...test, ...test2].map(...)`

Comment: @Edshav but then how to identify if isValid Y or N

Comment: @Edshav thing is the test2 array will always be N

Comment: It wasn't clear for me with those Y/N. But I got it now. So initial solution in the question is OK

Comment: title also says "concatenate" you can also use array `concat` as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not bad, you could also use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const test = ["SME", "ONE", "TWO"];
const test2 = ["RED"];

const result = [test, test2].flatMap(arr => {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return {
      item,
      isValid: arr === test,
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Here the last one is giving undefined

Comment: You can click "Run code snippet" to run the code and see the result, which is `[{"item":"SME","isValid":true},{"item":"ONE","isValid":true},{"item":"TWO","isValid":true},{"item":"RED","isValid":false}]`

Answer (score 0):

As you suggestet:

```
[...test, ...test2]
```

Or using `concat`

```
test.concat(test2)
```

Or without creating a new array, just pushing into `test`

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(test, test2)
```